# CSRF token mismatch API - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I'm trying to protect some routes, adding the CSRF verification that Laravel brings by default, I'm using Laravel v8 with sanctum, I have some APIs and I want to and tried to apply this security but I always get the same error: CSRF token mismatch.

**This is my file .env:**

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
APP_DOMAIN_NAME=api.app.localhost
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_DOMAIN=api.app.localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=https://api.app.localhost,localhost:3000,localhost:8000,127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:8000,localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000,localhost:8000,127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:8000,localhost
```

**File VerifyCsrfToken:**

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'telescope/*',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ];
}
```

**File session.php:**

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie'),

'encrypt' => true,
```

**File Kernel.php:**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
 'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'csrf' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ];
```

**Routes api.php:**

for those routes I am applying the csrf middleware, but I always get the same error: **CSRF token mismatch**.

```
Route::post('auth/register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->middleware('csrf');
Route::post('auth/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->middleware('csrf');
Route::get('user', [AuthController::class, 'user'])->middleware('csrf');
```

I am sending the csrf token by headers from postman like this:

**X-CSRF-TOKEN**. but it does not take it or apparently I am missing something to configure, and trying to create a test code to automatically store the XCSRF but nothing, first I call this route, so that it stores the csrf token: **sanctum/csrf-cookie** and then I call the routes where I apply the middlware sending the csrf by headers but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Postman needs specific configuration to run with Laravel API. You have to add pre-request script to Postman.

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie',
    method: 'GET'
}, function (error, response, { cookies }) {
    if (!error) {
        pm.environment.set('xsrf-cookie', cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'))
    }
})
```